# how to extract the entire database/application script in lotusscript?

Tags: search, lotusscript

I want to know some way to extract the entire script from all design elements, forms, agents, views etc. I know that in MS .NET we use reflection to get the entire code, classes, functions, properties, everything. I wonder if this is also possible using lotus script or any third party tool. In fact, my basic requirements is to search for anything in the entire script in the Lotus Designer using Ctrl+F but that doesn't help, whereas in Visual Studio.NET one can easily search the project or even the entire solution for the specific keyword.

Thanks,

baburman

Comment: Keep in mind, asking for off site resources is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for every string in database's code in Domino Designer at menu entry

```
Search / File...
```

If you still need to export all LotusScript code of a database,

- execute menu `File / Application / Design Synopsis...` or
- export database design as DXL

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.